# Reduce an array of matrices in tensorflow

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow

Functions like [`tf.reduce_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean) and [`tf.reduce_prod`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_prod) perform element wise operations to reduce a tensor along an axis. I have a tensor `R` with shape `(1000, 3, 3)`, a list of 3x3 matrices. What I'd like to do is **matrix** multiply them so I remain with a single 3x3 matrix. If this was numpy I could use

```
np.linalg.multi_dot(R)
```

How can I do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [tf.scan](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan): `tf.scan(lambda a, b: tf.matmul(a, b), R)[-1]`

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

R = np.random.rand(10, 3, 3)
R_reduced = np.linalg.multi_dot(R)

R_reduced_t = tf.scan(lambda a, b: tf.matmul(a, b), R)[-1]

with tf.Session() as sess:
  R_reduced_val = sess.run(R_reduced_t)
  diff = R_reduced_val - R_reduced
  print(diff)
```

This prints:

```
[[ -3.55271368e-15   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.77635684e-15   0.00000000e+00   3.55271368e-15]
 [ -1.77635684e-15   3.55271368e-15   0.00000000e+00]]
```