# In Tensorflow, is there a built in function to compute states over time given a transition matrix?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a system given by this recursive relationship: x<sub>t</sub> = A<sub>t</sub> x<sub>t-1</sub> + b<sub>t</sub>. I wish to compute x<sub>t</sub> for all t, with A<sub>t</sub>, b<sub>t</sub> and x<sub>0</sub> given. Is there are built-in function for that? If I use a loop it would be extremely slow. Thanks!

Comment: No, I do not think you can compute this without a for loop, it is a strictly sequential  computation

Comment: So `At` is different for each value of `t`, right?

Comment: Yes, At is different for every t

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is sort of a way. Let's say you have your `A` matrices in a 3D tensor with shape `(T, N, N)`, where `T` is the total number of time steps and `N` is the size of your vector. Similarly, `B` values are in a 2D tensor `(T, N)`. The first step in the computation would be:

```
x1 = A[0] @ x0 + B[0]
```

Where `@` represents matrix product. But you can convert this into a single matrix product. Suppose we add a value `1` at the end of `x0`, and we call that `x0p` (for prime):

```
x0p = tf.concat([x, [1]], axis=0)
```

And now we build a new 3D tensor `Ap` with shape `(T, N+1, N+1)`, such that for each `A[i]` we concatenate `B[i]` as a new column, and then we add a row with `N` zeros and a single one at the end:

```
AwithB = tf.concat([tf.concat([A, tf.expand_dims(B, 2)], axis=2)], axis=1)
AnewRow = tf.concat([tf.zeros((T, 1, N), A.dtype), tf.ones((T, 1, 1), A.dtype)], axis=2)
Ap = tf.concat([AwithB, AnewRow], axis=1)
```

As it turns out, you can now say:

```py
x1p = Ap[0] @ x0p
```

And therefore:

```py
x2p = Ap[1] @ x1p = Ap[1] @ Ap[0] @ x0p
```

So we just need to compute all the matrix product of all matrices in `Ap` across the first dimension. Unfortunately, there does not seem to be a direct operation to compute that with TensorFlow, but [you can do it relatively fast with `tf.scan`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45830743):

```py
Ap_prod = tf.scan(tf.matmul, Ap)[-1]
```

And with that you just have to do:

```py
xtp = Ap_prod @ x0p
```

Here is a proof of concept (the code is tweaked to support single examples and batches, either in the `A` and `B` values or in the `x`)

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def compute_state(a, b, x):
    s = tf.shape(a)
    t = s[-3]
    n = s[-1]
    # Add final 1 to x
    xp = tf.concat([x, tf.ones_like(x[..., :1])], axis=-1)
    # Add B column to A
    a_b = tf.concat([tf.concat([a, tf.expand_dims(b, axis=-1)], axis=-1)], axis=-2)
    # Make new final row for A
    a_row = tf.concat([tf.zeros_like(a[..., :1, :]),
                       tf.ones_like(a[..., :1, :1])], axis=-1)
    # Add new row to A
    ap = tf.concat([a_b, a_row], axis=-2)
    # Compute matrix product reduction
    ap_prod = tf.scan(tf.matmul, ap)[..., -1, :, :]
    # Compute final result
    outp = tf.linalg.matvec(ap_prod, xp)
    return outp[..., :-1]

#Test
tf.random.set_seed(0)
a = tf.random.uniform((10, 5, 5), -1, 1)
b = tf.random.uniform((10, 5), -1, 1)
x = tf.random.uniform((5,), -1, 1)
y = compute_state(a, b, x)
# Also works with batches of (a, b) or x
a = tf.random.uniform((100, 10, 5, 5), -1, 1)
b = tf.random.uniform((100, 10, 5), -1, 1)
x = tf.random.uniform((100, 5), -1, 1)
y = compute_state(a, b, x)
```